# post_per_page in wordpress not rendering properly on the page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i have this wordpress site and the pages will display images on it. Now my problem is when i add `post_per_page => '50'` then when i refresh the page the number of posts per page is not rendering correctly. Here is my code below.

```
<?php 
                        query_posts( array(
                        'post_per_page'  => 50,
                        'cat'=> '7',
                        'order' => 'ASC'
                    ) );

                ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="single-gallery anim-5-all interoors masonryImage mix span-4">
                    <div class="img-holder">
                        <?php
                            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
                            $url = $thumb['0'];
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?=$url; ?>" alt="">

                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.single-gallery -->
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Now it will display 9 images on the page. Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first, I fond mistake in your query arguments

```
'post_per_page'  => 50,
```

There is no such argument for wp_query loop use instead it

```
'posts_per_page'  => 50,
```

For a second there is quote from a wodpress codex about [query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) function

> Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t
>   intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach
>   to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided
>   wherever possible. In most cases, there are better, more performant
>   options for modifying the main query such as via the ‘pre_get_posts’
>   action within WP_Query.

I can recomend you to use standard wordpress loop

```
<?php
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'cat'            => '7',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
];

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop


while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="single-gallery anim-5-all interoors masonryImage mix span-4">
        <div class="img-holder">
            <?php
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );
                $url = $thumb['0'];
            ?>

            <img src="<?=$url; ?>" alt="">

        </div>
    </div><!-- /.single-gallery -->
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just use this one query_posts with posts_per_page